# Using ISO8601 dates in Ecto Timestamps

Tags: date, datetime, elixir, ecto

[Browsing through Ecto.DateTime](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.DateTime.html#content), it seems to be deprecated in favor of `:naive_datetime`. I'd like to store the timestamp in the most accurate representation possible, and I can't seem to find what `:naive_datetime` provides me. From what I can tell, `Ecto.DateTime` is convertible to ISO8601, but it doesn't give any indication on how a naive datetime is stored in the database.

Is there other possible options to specify when creating timestamps like so:

```
schema "test" do 
  field :name
  timestamps type: :iso8601 # This doesn't work 
end
```

I haven't been able to find a list of other possible options. Am I stuck with naive datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What’s wrong with `NaiveDateTime`? How might the time be *more* accurate? Just make sure your servers run in `"Etc/UTC"` and you are all set.

It sounds like you misunderstand what `iso8601` is: it’s just a string representation. Also, using [`NaiveDateTime.to_iso8601/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/NaiveDateTime.html#to_iso8601/2) one always might get `ISO8601` representation of `NaiveDateTime`:

```
NaiveDateTime.utc_now |> NaiveDateTime.to_iso8601
#⇒ "2017-10-27T05:15:42.355701"
```

Don’t be afraid of the term “naïve.” In this context it means “it does not store the timezone.” Nothing more.

Comment: Yeah to be honest I just don't understand what a naive datetime is. If you could specify it in the answer, and how to set up a server in that way, I'll go ahead and check this off. I'm sure I'm just missing something. For reference I'm dealing with some time sensitive data, so a few seconds difference is a huge deal to me.

Comment: What do you mean by “specify it in the answer”? Are you afraid of the word “naïve”? It’s a system clock time with a **nanosecond** precision.

Comment: Yeah, I don't exactly understand what "naive" means in the context of datetime, I'm sorry.

Comment: BTW, Elixir core is open source: [`NaiveDateTime`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.5.2/lib/elixir/lib/calendar/naive_datetime.ex#L1).

Comment: “naïve” in this context means “it does not store the timezone.” Nothing more.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll mark this then. If you could put that in the answer for people passing through I'm sure they'll appreicate not having to dig through the comments.